# How to hold the message in server until user become online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have developed a one to one (private)chat using socket-io. When A and B login together i can successfully exchange message between them. If any one of the user is in offline status i want to hold the message in the server and push once the user become online. How to hold the message in server when user is in offline state ?

```html
var obj = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('connected', function(ele){
    console.log(ele.nameTo,ele.nameFrom);
    obj[ele.nameFrom] = socket.id;
    console.log(obj);
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.to(obj[msg.nameTo]).emit('chat message', msg);
      io.to(obj[msg.nameFrom]).emit('chat message', msg);
```

my server.js

Comment: Keep the message in the database (or cache it somewhere) and show it to the user once he's back online (show the stored messages)

Comment: Keep message in the database and store a token for user into session and user cookie. For each login check user cookie if there is a token and token is in sessions read user massage from db and show to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good that you are using socket.io.

Emit one event once user is online from client to server. Catch that event on server so server will send message to client.

e.g. 
Once user online execute following code at client side.

```
socket.emit('get_message');
```

On server write following event handler

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('get_message',{ // this event handler will get fired
      // get message from database and send it to client by using following code
      socket.send({'message'})
    });
})
```

Comment: How to show that these messages are new because the fetch get all the messages

Answer (score 0):

It is important to put all the messages you send to the user into a datastore (db/cache/etc) so that no data is lost due to an unsuccessful message transmission.

Mark them as sent only if you get a successful ack from the user. (Socket-io supports acknowledgements see: https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)

Whenever messages are generated while a user is offline put those messages to the datastore and mark them as `unsent` using some sort of flag.

Once the user is online, he will connect to the server via the socket.io connection. During this event, you should scan the database/cache for any messages that were not sent. After you send the messages successfully to the user, mark them with a flag specifying that they were sent.